# Grabbing different elements with BeautifulSoup: avoid duplicating in nested elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5lib

i want to grab different content (classes) from an lokal saved website (the python documentation) using BeautifulSoup4, so i use this code for doing that (index.html is this saved website: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html )

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))
f = open('test.html','w')
f.truncate
classes= soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class': ['class', 'method','function','describe', 'attribute', 'data', 'clasmethod', 'staticmethod']})
print(classes,file=f) 
f.close()
```

The filehandler is only for result-output and has no effect on the problem itself.

My problem is that the results are nested. For example the method "__eq__ (exporter) will be found 1. inside of the class and 2. as a method standalone.

So i want to remove all the results inside of other results to have every result on the same hierarchical level . How can i do this? Or is it even possible to "ignore" that content in the first step? I hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell `find` to ignore nested `dl` elements; all you can do is ignore matches that appear in the `.descendants`:

```
matches = []
for dl in soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class': ['class', 'method','function','describe', 'attribute', 'data', 'clasmethod', 'staticmethod']})
    if any(dl in m.descendants for m in matches):
        # child of already found element
        continue
    matches.append(dl)
```

If you want nested elements and no parents, use:

```
matches = []
for dl in soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class': ['class', 'method','function','describe', 'attribute', 'data', 'clasmethod', 'staticmethod']})
    matches = [m for m in matches if dl not in m.descendants]
    matches.append(dl)
```

If you wanted to pull apart the tree and *remove* elements from the tree, use:

```
matches = soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class': ['class', 'method','function','describe', 'attribute', 'data', 'clasmethod', 'staticmethod']})
for element in matches:
    element.extract()  # remove from tree (and parent `dl` matches)
```

but you may want to adjust your text extracting instead.

Comment: I just realized that the nested <dl>-elements are now part of the parent-element and not standalone (as i wished no duplicates). But in fact i need all elements on the same hierarchical level.
I can't see a option to make that possible with changing just a order in that code above. Am i correct?

Comment: @sv0101: it's not clear what you are asking then; the above code only includes matches that are not nested. What do you mean by 'same hierarchical level'? The posted code produces elements all at the *top* level.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. The above code creates this output for me: [test.html](http://wildermannonline.de/sven/test.html) while using ***** as debugbing-delimiter. 
Let's have a look for example at the method __eq__: This is nested in the class memoryview but i want __eq__ to be separated (and so surrounded by **** in debug-mode). I want this behavior for all nested elements (and so for all methods inside of classes).  
I hope it is now clear what i mean. Feel free to edit my question.

Comment: So you want to have the *nested* elements with no further children only?

Comment: I want the childs without the parents and vice versa. So i that example i want the class without the methods and every method standalone.

Comment: @sv0101: It is becoming clearer what you want, but you need to be *explicit* about what you are trying to extract here. You can *remove* elements from the tree, so that parent `dl` statements no longer will list their children. That's more what I think you want to do here.