# BeautifulSoup: Search from leaf to root to get the "deepest" elements first?

Tags: python, documentation, beautifulsoup, lxml, html5lib

For a research project similar to [this one](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/TSE.2013.12) I want to extract all "documentation units" from the [python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/)
A ***documentation unit*** in the python documentation can be (as html-meta tag):

- a ***method*** (dl class: method)
- a ***class***  (dl class: class)
- a ***section*** (div class: section)

And these should be nested: A ***section*** contains several ***class**es*, which contain several ***method**s*. But in fact that is very irregular.

**Example1:** If a section contains several classes and methods: I want to get each method alone and each class without the methods (which I already got) and the section without the classes (which I already have in that case) and without the methods (which I also already have) but with the rest of the it (as there is a lot of additional stuff in there)

**Example2:** If a method or a class has no section in which they appear, I also want them as mentioned above and must not forget them.

*Note:* Doesn't make it easier but I would like to get all of them in a list which has the **same order as in the original documentation.**

I tried it with BeautifulSoup but I guess for that purpose I need to search "from leaf to root" to get the deepest elements first - which is (AFAIK) not supported by BeautifulSoup4.

[First I thought the problem is to avoid duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174251/grabbing-different-elements-with-beautifulsoup-avoid-duplicating-in-nested-elem) but in fact that is not the main problem.

I appreciate your hints.

Comment: Surely **you want a tree**, not a *"list which has the same order as in the original"*. I don't understand anything you wrote from *"Example 1... Example 2... Note"*; these seem to conflict with each other, and also with BS. And I don't even understand the comment *"Example2: If a method or a class has no section in which they appear, I also want them as mentioned above and must not forget them."* Please edit to clarify. Are you referring to how tree-building should treat children nodes? sibling nodes? descendants? all of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is not possible.

So what i did to solve this problem is to iterate over the elements (which i got using .descendants) again and again and then i replaced the nested-elements with a placeholder to make that change visible (using replace_with).

As i used .descendants before, the nested elements are stored anyway.